# WordPress custom setting not showing in the REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to register a custom setting field in my WordPress dashboard using the following code:

```
function register_fields()
{

   register_setting('general', 'live_streaming_url', array(
     'show_in_rest' => true,
     'type' => 'string',
     'default' => 'public',
   ));
    add_settings_field('live_streaming_url', '<label for="live_streaming_url">'.__('Live 
    Streaming Link' , 'live_streaming_url' ).'</label>' , 'print_custom_field', 'general');
}

function print_custom_field()
{
    $value = get_option( 'live_streaming_url', '' );
    echo '<input type="text" id="live_streaming_url" name="live_streaming_url" style="width:250px;" value="' . $value . '" />';
}

add_filter('admin_init', 'register_fields');
```

The fields is working perfectly on the dashboard but it's not showing in the REST API when I call

http://MY_DOMAIN_NAME/wp-json/wp/v2/settings

**Note:**  All the other fields are returned in the API expect that custom one.
**Note:**  I am using WordPress 5.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this script to make them appear in WP REST API

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_fields');
```